# How to send the given JSON as parameters in the POST request using Alamofire in Swift 3?

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I have JSON as follows which has to be included as body for POST request,

```
    {
      "type" : "myData",
      "condition" : {"projectid": 40}
    }
```

How should my POST request be formed using Alamofire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply create parameter `Dictionary`.

```
let parameters: [String:Any] = [ "type" : "myData", "condition" : ["projectid" : 40]]
```

Now pass this `parameters` dictionary with `Alamofire`.

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @SeaWarrior404 Welcome mate :)